# Check whether or not $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over n\sqrt[n]{n}}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Check whether or not $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over n\sqrt[n]{n}}$ converges.

I tried few things but it wouldn't work out. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you try taking advantage of the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \root n\of n=1$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $limsup$? 
And yes I tried, but then I thought that $lim$ don't take the supremum but what it gets when $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel $\limsup=\lim$ when the limit exists.

Comment: I think this series compares with $\sum \frac1{n \log{n}}$.

Comment: @RonGordon yes, if you show $\sqrt[n]{n}\le M$ ($M=2$ is easy enough) then you can compare with that one.

Comment: Show that $\sqrt[n]{n}\lt 2$ for all $n\ge 1$. Equivalently show that $n\lt 2^n$, which can be done by induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

Using the limit comparison test with the harmonic series we see

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {\cancel{(1/n)}\cdot 1\over \cancel{(1/n)}\sqrt[n]{n}}=1$$

hence the series diverges since the harmonic series does.

Comment: Thank you! 
I have been trying to  do this and somehow didn't manage to.

Comment: I meant to write the comment under the main question. Shifting.

Answer (score 8):

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$ then for sufficiently large $n$ we have

$$\frac1{n\sqrt[n]n}\ge \frac1{2n}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\ge {1\over n}$ from some point?

Comment: Doesn't this hold for all $n\in\mathbb{R^+}$?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel no, $\sqrt[n]{n}>1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: But from some point $n\sqrt[n]{n}$ is strictly smaller then $2n$...

Comment: In this case $1$ is sufficiently large;) @Lukas

Answer (score 1):

$$n \cdot n^{1/n} = n e^{\log{n}/n}  = n \left [ 1+ \frac{\log{n}}{n} + O\left ( \frac{\log^2{n}}{n^2} \right ) \right ] = n + \log{n}+ O\left ( \frac{\log^2{n}}{n} \right )  $$

Now,for sufficiently large $n$ (i.e., $n \gt 4$), $n+\log{n} \lt n \log{n} $, so the sum is larger than

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac1{n \log{n}} $$

which diverges.